# how to implement goto in tcl

Tags: tcl

I wanted to know how to implement GOTO in tcl.
I am writing a test case where I have say 5 steps.
If my step 1 fails I don't want to proceed further and I want to skip the existing things and goto a common clean up section.

Please help me with if there are any GOTO commands in tcl.

Thanks,
Ramya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *no* `goto` in Tcl, and for relatively technical reasons it's impossible to implement one.

But you can do what you're after in other ways. Since you're dealing with test cases, I hope you're using the `tcltest` package for the job. With that, you can specify cleanup code quite easily:

```
tcltest::test test-1.1 "verify that the foo works" -setup {
    allocate some resources
} -body {
    whatever to do the test...
    return [our results]
} -cleanup {
    drop those resources
    make sure that we are nice and clean
} -result "the expected test result"
```

You can skip out of the body of a test easily by just doing a `return`; the `tcltest::test` command will detect it and treat that as the result. It is usually better to try to keep each test independent of the others though: that makes it much easier to track down what's going wrong when a test fails.

If you're not using `tcltest`, you are still best refactoring into something where you can use `return` to skip out early. You can combine that with `try…finally…` (either natively in Tcl 8.6, or with [this code on the Tcler's Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/990)) to make things easy:

```
proc doThings {} {
    try {
        # do thing-1
        if {$no_more} return
        # do thing-2
        if {$no_more} return
        # do thing-3
        if {$no_more} return
        # do thing-4
        if {$no_more} return
        # do thing-5
    } finally {
        # do cleanup
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue that really blocks `goto` is that it's very hard to get labeling of statements right — while we could handle labels in blocks that an exception bubbles up through, any label in a sub-block not currently in the execution context would be invisible — without which you can't actually go to anywhere at all; it would be possible to add special cases for built-in commands, but against the spirit of the language. Other, higher-level syntactic constructs _are_ possible though, so the absence of `goto` isn't felt very much in practice.

Comment: Or you could write using [TAL](http://wiki.tcl.tk/28070), but that's not for the faint-hearted!