# Is there any label concept available in TCL?

Tags: switch-statement, tcl, label

Actually my requirement is while choosing the label it will redirect to specific place where i have give the description.

Example

```
set a 20

switch -- $a {
"20" : goto check
"abc" : goto check1
}
Label 20:
puts "Given value is integer"
Label abc:
puts "Given value is alpha"
```

likewise is there any option available in TCL

Comment: You could use a `proc`, but is there an issue with executing within the switch itself?

Comment: No i guess, is there any other option?

Comment: Not that I know of... Maybe Donal could shed some light. He should be around soon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to implement goto in tcl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403083/how-to-implement-goto-in-tcl)

Answer (score 1):

Tcl doesn't support `goto` at all; it's low-level semantics are incompatible with `goto`, though they work fine with just about all higher-level concepts (such as structured programming, state machines, etc.) What to do instead depends on exactly what you're doing; toy examples aren't very helpful here.

---

The one option for a direct `goto` is to use `tcl::unsupported::assemble` (Tcl 8.6 only).

```
proc foo a {
    tcl::unsupported::assemble {
        expr {
            $a eq 20
        }
        jumpTrue check
        expr {
            $a eq "abc"
        }
        jumpTrue check2
        jump end
    label check
        eval {
            puts "Given value is integer"
        }
        pop
    label check2
        eval {
            puts "Given value is alpha"
        }
        pop
    label end
        # There *must* be one result value pushed onto the stack at the end
        push ""
    }
}

puts "before"
foo 20
puts "mid-1"
foo abc
puts "mid-2"
foo 3.14
puts "after"
```

That lets you write a direct `goto` (the `jumpTrue` and `jump`; there's also a `jumpFalse`) to a `label` and the `expr` and `eval` pseudo-opcodes let you inject an expression evaluation or script rather than writing everything by hand. *However*, the writing of bytecode by hand will get very boring very quickly and the command isn't supported (because we don't really like our bytecode). This is how to do it, but it's truly not encouraged. In particular, you need take care to manage the evaluation stack right; both `expr` and `eval` push one value, and the net stack effect of the whole bytecode needs to be to push exactly one value (or throw an exception).

Also, the assembler doesn't allow all bytecode instructions that the engine knows. Some are restricted because they're unsafe (except how the compiler uses them) and others because we've no idea how to describe them sensibly! There's not much help for what the legal bytecodes really are either…